# Is Romeo and Juliet a tragedy?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A friend of mine introduced me this riddle in a game some time ago in prose and I decided to try to make it in verse. It's a well known one. I hope it's a bit easier than the original because I was allowed some probing questions.

> I enter the bedroom and immediately see
>
> Romeo and Juliet dead, lying on the floor
>
> Water and shattered glass all around me
>
> What else am I supposed to look for?
>
> Evidence and a culprit, my partner agrees
>
> Everything clean but the garden backdoor
>
> Some wet footprints towards the tree
>
> There, staring at us, the perpetrator!
>
> The crime wasn't that hard to foresee
>
> The predator has done similar before
>
> Poor couple, drowned to some degree
>
> A bit confusing that sounds in the report
>
> My dear and old friends ceased to be
>
> An aquarium was their doom and my sore
>
> Black story... What just happened here?
>
> In just one phrase, simple, no more.

Comment: "Is Romeo and Juliet a tragedy?" Umm, yes. Yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happened was

> They were fish

I enter the bedroom and immediately see

Romeo and Juliet dead, lying on the floor

> Their tank broke.

Water and shattered glass all around me

What else am I supposed to look for?

> The tank was made out of glass.

Evidence and a culprit, my partner agrees

Everything clean but the garden backdoor

> Yes.

Some wet footprints towards the tree

There, staring at us, the perpetrator!

> Maybe a cat?

The crime wasn't that hard to foresee

The predator has done similar before

> Yeah.

Poor couple, drowned to some degree

A bit confusing that sounds in the report

> Drowned of air.

My dear and old friends ceased to be

An aquarium was their doom and my sore

> Yeah.

Black story... What just happened here?

In just one phrase, simple, no more.

> Fish.

Comment: Sniped! +1 my friend, well done

Comment: Geez... hahah that was so fast. What were the most evident hints?

Comment: Well I just have seen a similar puzzle before :D +1 I've enjoyed this. @villasv

Comment: Awww, yeah I knew it was a bit famous puzzle. At least I hope I did well with a poem version then. Thanks ;-)

Comment: It might be a bit too late to say this, but congratz on the $10k$ rep! (And nice answer, too, like always) :D

Comment: @user477343, thank you very much!! :D

Comment: I apologise if my following question is personal, but are you a professional riddle-maker or solver if they even exist? I mean, I'm being serious, you do  solve these riddles very quickly and make good ones, too. I am aware you have not mentioned anything in your profile apart from unrelated Rot13 (well technically, it *is* related... all in the hands of the Lord), but I am just curious. When I am older, I would love to make riddles and puzzles for newspapers, hahah :P

Comment: @user477343, No, just an intense puzzle fanatic. :)

Comment: Hahah, even Puzzling.SE called you that! I mean, you got the fanatic badge! :D